How can I know whether a function is consteval'ed?
A constexpr function can be called during the runtime, or in the compilation time if its arguments are constexpr.
I hope to implement something like:
constexpr auto f() {
    /* some code ... */

    if constexpr ("called in compilation time") {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }

    /* rest code ... */
}

How do I do this?

C++23 introduced if consteval, which does exactly what you want:
constexpr auto f() {
    if consteval {
        return "constant evaluated";
    } else {
        return "runtime evaluated";
    }
}

Demo

C++20 had std::is_constant_evaluated(), which does the same thing.  Note that it should not be used in an if constexpr statement, since it will always return true in that case:
constexpr auto f() {
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
        return "constant evaluated";
    } else {
        return "runtime evaluated";
    }
}

Demo

Prior to C++20 there was no way to determine if a function was constant evaluated.

I expect the first line of the output of https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5af4d818ca3e7ec8 to be 1.  I think f(1) should be computed in the compilation time.

@shynur the only way to force a constexpr function to be called at compile to is to use it in a constexpr context, like assigning its return value to a constexpr variable.

Just that something can be consteval'ed does not mean it has to. To enforce consteval you need to for example use it as a NTTP.

Thank you guys.  I test it using g++ -O3 and now it is forced to be constevaled.
